# What is the Best way to prevent from Spam?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have one website and having alot of spam emails and signup. I have added plugin
https://www.mgt-commerce.com/magento-akismet-spam-protection-extension.html
and It use the akismet api for spam detection. Is any other way so i can add that on code level. Please let me know useful suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to prevent spam google captcha. Below links for more reference.

### Links

http://bit.ly/V7K5C7

http://bit.ly/2az1Y8V